# android: Custom (compund) control in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a srange trouble wit the ListView:
I've created the compound control

```
public class TopicControl extends LinearLayout
....

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTopicHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnTopicTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="btnTopicTitle"
        ></Button>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTopicBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:tag="llTopicBar"
        >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_calendar"
            ></Button>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_person"
            ></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvTopicText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>
</merge>
```

In that control I implemented hiding/showing llTopicBar on btnTopicTitle click.

The problem is that when I add that component to ListView, after pressing btnTopicTitle, llTopicBar becomes visible not only for the clicked item, but for every **second** LstViewItem.

after adding "parent" verification llTopicBar becomes visible for every **4th** item in the ListView.

```
Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getParent().getParent() == getThis())
    llTopicBar.setVisibility(llTopicBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Could you please help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was within reusing Views for ListView during scrolling.